# bootstrap toggle switch to original value angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

```
[enter image description here][1]
The file to hack is bootstrap original file 

import {Component, Input, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, DoCheck, SimpleChanges, ViewChild, Renderer, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked,
      trigger,
      state,
      style,
      transition,
      animate,
      ViewEncapsulation
    } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
      selector: 'switch',
      template: `<div #main class="bootstrap-switch bootstrap-switch-wrapper bootstrap-switch-animate bootstrap-switch-off" [ngClass]="_sizeClass + ' ' + _disabledClass" (click)="toggleStatus()">
        <div #container class="bootstrap-switch-container"  [@statusChange]="_statusStr" >
            <span #on class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on" [ngClass]="_onColor" [ngStyle]="{'min-width': _minWidth +'px'}">{{onText}}</span>
            <span #mid class="bootstrap-switch-label"></span>
            <span #off class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off " [ngClass]="_offColor">{{offText}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
      styles: [`/* ========================================================================
      * bootstrap-switch - v3.3.2
      * http://www.bootstrap-switch.org
      * ========================================================================
      * Copyright 2012-2013 Mattia Larentis
      *
      * ========================================================================
      * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
      * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
      * You may obtain a copy of the License at
      *
      *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
      *
      * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
      * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
      * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
      * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
      * limitations under the License.
      * ========================================================================
      */
    
     .bootstrap-switch {
       display: inline-block;
       direction: ltr;
       cursor: pointer;
       border-radius: 4px;
       border: 1px solid;
       border-color: #cccccc;
       position: relative;
       text-align: left;
       overflow: hidden;
       line-height: 8px;
       z-index: 0;
       -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
       -ms-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;
       vertical-align: middle;
       -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
       transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-container {
       display: inline-block;
       top: 0;
       border-radius: 4px;
       -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       background: #fff;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on,
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off,
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-label {
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       cursor: pointer;
       display: inline-block !important;
       height: 100%;
       padding: 6px 12px;
       font-size: 14px;
       line-height: 20px;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on,
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off {
       text-align: center;
       z-index: 1;
       white-space: nowrap;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-primary,
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-primary {
       color: #fff;
       background: #428bca;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-info,
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-info {
       color: #fff;
       background: #5bc0de;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-success,
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-success {
       color: #fff;
       background: #5cb85c;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-warning,
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-warning {
       background: #f0ad4e;
       color: #fff;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-danger,
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-danger {
       color: #fff;
       background: #d9534f;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-default,
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-default {
       color: #000;
       background: #eeeeee;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-label {
       text-align: center;
       margin-top: -1px;
       margin-bottom: -1px;
       z-index: 100;
       color: #333333;
       background: #ffffff;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on {
       border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
       border-top-left-radius: 3px;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off {
       border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
       border-top-right-radius: 3px;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch input[type='radio'],
     .bootstrap-switch input[type='checkbox'] {
       position: absolute !important;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       opacity: 0;
       filter: alpha(opacity=0);
       z-index: -1;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch input[type='radio'].form-control,
     .bootstrap-switch input[type='checkbox'].form-control {
       height: auto;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-mini .bootstrap-switch-handle-on,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-mini .bootstrap-switch-handle-off,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-mini .bootstrap-switch-label {
       padding: 1px 5px;
       font-size: 12px;
       line-height: 1.5;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-small .bootstrap-switch-handle-on,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-small .bootstrap-switch-handle-off,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-small .bootstrap-switch-label {
       padding: 5px 10px;
       font-size: 12px;
       line-height: 1.5;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-large .bootstrap-switch-handle-on,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-large .bootstrap-switch-handle-off,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-large .bootstrap-switch-label {
       padding: 6px 16px;
       font-size: 18px;
       line-height: 1.33;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-disabled,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-readonly,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-indeterminate {
       cursor: default !important;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-disabled .bootstrap-switch-handle-on,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-readonly .bootstrap-switch-handle-on,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-indeterminate .bootstrap-switch-handle-on,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-disabled .bootstrap-switch-handle-off,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-readonly .bootstrap-switch-handle-off,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-indeterminate .bootstrap-switch-handle-off,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-disabled .bootstrap-switch-label,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-readonly .bootstrap-switch-label,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-indeterminate .bootstrap-switch-label {
       opacity: 0.5;
       filter: alpha(opacity=50);
       cursor: default !important;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-animate .bootstrap-switch-container {
       -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.5s;
       transition: margin-left 0.5s;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-inverse .bootstrap-switch-handle-on {
       border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
       border-top-left-radius: 0;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
       border-top-right-radius: 3px;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-inverse .bootstrap-switch-handle-off {
       border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
       border-top-right-radius: 0;
       border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
       border-top-left-radius: 3px;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-focused {
       border-color: #66afe9;
       outline: 0;
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
       box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-on .bootstrap-switch-label,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-inverse.bootstrap-switch-off .bootstrap-switch-label {
       border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
       border-top-right-radius: 3px;
     }
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-off .bootstrap-switch-label,
     .bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-inverse.bootstrap-switch-on .bootstrap-switch-label {
       border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
       border-top-left-radius: 3px;
     }`],
      animations: [
        trigger('statusChange', [
          state('false', style({ transform: 'translateX(-33.333%)' })),
          state('true', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
          transition('true <=> false', animate('200ms'))
        ])
      ]
    })
    export class BootstrapSwitchComponent implements DoCheck, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked {
    
      @ViewChild('on') _onSpan: ElementRef;
      @ViewChild('off') _offSpan: ElementRef;
      @ViewChild('mid') _midSpan: ElementRef;
      @ViewChild('container') _container: ElementRef;
      @ViewChild('main') _main: ElementRef;
    
    
      // public properties
      @Input() status = false;
      @Output() statusChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    
      @Input() onText = 'yes';
      @Input() offText = 'no';
      @Input() onColor = 'bootstrap-switch-info';
      @Input() offColor = 'bootstrap-switch-default';
      @Input() size = 'mini';
      @Input() disabled = false;
    
      _statusStr = 'false';
    
      // styles properties
      _onColor = 'bootstrap-switch-info';
      _offColor = 'bootstrap-switch-default';
      _minWidth = 60;
      _sizeClass = 'bootstrap-switch-normal';
      _disabledClass = '';
      _needCalculateWidth = false;
    
      constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
        this._calculateSize();
      }
    
    
    
      toggleStatus(): void {
        if (!this.disabled) {
          this.status = !this.status;
          this._statusStr = this.status.toString();
          this.statusChange.emit(this.status);
        }
      }
    
      private _setDisabled(disabled: boolean): void {
        if (disabled) {
          this._disabledClass = 'bootstrap-switch-disabled'
        } else {
          this._disabledClass = '';
        }
      }
    
      private _setColor(switchLabel: string, value: string): void {
        let color = '';
        let defaultColor = 'bootstrap-switch-info';
    
        if (switchLabel === 'off') {
          defaultColor = 'bootstrap-switch-default';
        }
    
        switch (value) {
          case 'default':
            color = defaultColor;
            break;
          case 'blue':
            color = 'bootstrap-switch-primary';
            break;
          case 'sky-blue':
            color = 'bootstrap-switch-info';
            break;
          case 'red':
            color = 'bootstrap-switch-danger';
            break;
          case 'yellow':
            color = 'bootstrap-switch-warning';
            break;
          case 'green':
            color = 'bootstrap-switch-success';
            break;
          case 'gray':
            color = 'bootstrap-switch-default';
            break;
        }
    
        if (switchLabel === 'off') {
          this._offColor = color;
        } else {
          this._onColor = color;
        }
      }
    
      private _calculateWidth(): void {
        if (this._onSpan) {
          this.renderer.setElementStyle(this._onSpan.nativeElement, 'width', '');
          this.renderer.setElementStyle(this._midSpan.nativeElement, 'width', '');
          this.renderer.setElementStyle(this._offSpan.nativeElement, 'width', '');
          this.renderer.setElementStyle(this._main.nativeElement, "width", "");
    
          const width = Math.max(this._onSpan.nativeElement.clientWidth, this._offSpan.nativeElement.clientWidth, this._minWidth);
    
          this.renderer.setElementStyle(this._onSpan.nativeElement, 'width', width.toString() + 'px');
          this.renderer.setElementStyle(this._midSpan.nativeElement, 'width', (width - 10).toString() + 'px');
          this.renderer.setElementStyle(this._offSpan.nativeElement, 'width', width.toString() + 'px');
          this.renderer.setElementStyle(this._container.nativeElement, 'width', (width * 3).toString() + 'px');
          this.renderer.setElementStyle(this._main.nativeElement, 'width', (width * 2).toString() + 'px');
        }
      }
    
      private _calculateSize(): void {
        switch (this.size) {
          case 'mini':
            this._sizeClass = 'bootstrap-switch-mini';
            this._minWidth = 25;
            break;
          case 'small':
            this._sizeClass = 'bootstrap-switch-small';
            this._minWidth = 30;
            break;
          case 'normal':
            this._sizeClass = 'bootstrap-switch-normal';
            this._minWidth = 60;
            break;
          case 'large':
            this._sizeClass = 'bootstrap-switch-large';
            this._minWidth = 80;
            break;
        }
    
        this._needCalculateWidth = true;
      }
    
      ngAfterViewChecked(){
        if(this._needCalculateWidth){
          this._calculateWidth();
          this._needCalculateWidth = false;
        }
      }
    
      ngDoCheck() {
        //const log: string[] = [];
        console.log('changes',this.status);
        if(this.status == true) {
          this._statusStr = 'true';
        } else {
          this._statusStr = 'false';
        }
        
        // for (const propName in changes) {
        //   if (changes.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        //     const changedProp = changes[propName];
        //     const from = changedProp.previousValue;
        //     const value = changedProp.currentValue;
    
            
      
        
      }
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        // this._calculateSize('normal');
        // this._calculateWidth();
      }
    }
    
   
    I have send option which is a bootstrap switch, Only one can be yes at  a time.
 If the switch of one more row is clicked to yes there should be a notification along with which the switch again go towards no.

The switch code 
        <ng-container *ngIf="column.actions.type === 'evMan'">
                    <span> Yes 
                      <switch  
                        [size]="mini"
                        (statusChange)="onChangeSwitch($event,row)" 
                        [status]="(getData(row, 'send_to_evman')) === 'true' ? true : false"> 
                      </switch> No 
                    </span>**{{(getData(row, 'send_to_evman'))}}**
                  </ng-container>
        
        I get the value to false but the status property doesnt switch it back because the original value of switch is false 
        and u have to again send it to false state because you cant make it switch to true since other row has a already a switch to true state.
```

The bold interpolation get the data, how to make the status property to accept switch value and turn it to false.
How should you get the status to change on its own.
I have tried angular 2 npm switch as well as bootstrap switch both have same issue , what is the work around if it is not possible

Can some please help at this.
Please look into the above image.